# Django : uploading images

Tags: python, django, image, upload

I've been spending many hours trying to find a way to upload images in Django.

If you want to upload it to models it's very easy, but as soon as you don't want models it's impossible, which is weird since it's integrated in the models. Any other framework would have a simple integrated solution. I've looked for plugins, same thing, impossible to find one.

Here is the admin view I added:

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()

@staff_member_required
def uploadImage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form.is_multipart():
            return HttpResponse('so now what?')

    context = { 'form': form }
    return render_to_response('blogs/admin/upload.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

So my question: Is there an easy way to upload images with Django without using models?

Comment: have you looked here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: yes and there is no sign of already made code that allows Image upload. The code they give doesn't look for duplicates.

Comment: @yuvi : Is there an easy way to upload images with Django without using models? All the frameworks I know do that.

Comment: Yes. Use a form like in the link @clime gives you. A form doesn't have to be linked to any model and have almost the exact validation capabilities and features

Comment: it doesn't check for same names, it just overwrite it.

Comment: You can add your own [customize validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) to avoid duplicates (or, if you like doing things in a convoluted way like I do, you can use a dynamic model and create a dynamic model form to control it. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21516688/2387772) for an example)

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea why you keep going on about image uploads being tied to models. It isn't, in any way at all: there is no code in the Model class that deals with image uploads. Even the File and Image fields don't have any code dealing with uploads: all they do is call out to the Storage class, which is exactly what you should do.

clime has already given you the link to the [file upload docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/). As you should be able to see, they explain fully how to upload a file from a form, with absolutely no mention of models at all.

Comment: I think he's having a problem understaing how to validate that there's no file with the same name.